# AlignBaseLine but avoid circular dependecies in Android layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I try to align a CheckBox to the right of a EditText. The problem is I have a circular dependency if I do it my way.

I want to align the Powerbox and Landline checkboxes at the BaseLine of the EditTexts.

[image: screenshot]

Currently I use this code

```
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txt_elec_box"
            android:id="@+id/electricityBox"
            android:layout_below="@id/streetText"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:id="@+id/streetNumText"
            android:layout_below="@id/streetText"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/electricityBox"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/electricityBox"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:hint="@string/txt_street_check"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/electricityBox" />

         ....

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txt_landline"
            android:id="@+id/landlineBox"
            android:layout_below="@id/familyNameText"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"                  
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:id="@+id/phoneNumberText"
            android:layout_below="@id/familyNameText"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/landlineBox"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/landlineBox"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/landlineBox"  />
```

As you can see I used

```
android:paddingTop="5dp"
```

at the checkboxes to make them be a little more at the bottom but want I want to do is this

```
android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/phoneNumberText"
```

but then a circular dependency arises.

I also want the checkboxes to be aligned horizontal too if this is possible in a not-hard-coded-width way (The perfect alignment in the screenshot is by chance using the english version of my app).

Comment: You can invert the order and put the `landlineBox` `toRightOf` the `phoneNumberText`

Comment: Yes, but then the checkbox text is splitted in 2 lines if the display size is not big enough. I want the EditText to take as much space as possible but not more than the checkboxes need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make your parent layout be LinearLayout, then for each row item in your layout, make it a RelativeLayout. Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/streetText">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/streetNumText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/electricityBox"
        android:hint="@string/txt_street_check" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/electricityBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/txt_elec_box" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It works. The vertical alignment is still of but I guess that is another story. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a LinearLayout and use gravity(or layout_gravity)="center"

Comment: Not working for me. I want left alignment of the EditTexts. Also the checkbox texts get cut off.